# Graphics: Moving Images and aligning with text

Tags: macros, graphics

So currently I have this code written out:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\includegraphics[width=60mm, scale=0.3]{titanium-distillation-vessel.jpg}
\caption{Argon Vessel, containing TiCl$_{4}$ and Mg}
\label{overflow}
\end{figure}
```

And the picture sits just on the left of the page, but I don't know any command to let it sit next to a paragraph, like on the left of the page will be writing and on the right I wanted an image, but so far the image just separates the paragraph in two. So is there a way to move the image so that it is side-by-side with a plot of text? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to fix the position, drop the `figure` environment, use `caption` package and say `\captionof{figure}{Argon Vessel....}` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description in the question, this solution proposes a parallel `minipage` structure to place text and image side by side with `adjustbox` package. For alignment `c(enter)` can be changed to `b(ottom)` `t(op)`. Remove the [demo] option in the `graphicx` for real implementation.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[show frame,paper size={20cm,15cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.49\textwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.49\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[valign=c,width=\textwidth]{titanium-distillation-vessel.jpg}
\captionof{figure}{Argon Vessel, containing TiCl$_{4}$ and Mg}
\label{overflow}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```